# Issue in user input or text file data in sentiment analysis

Tags: python, nltk, sentiment-analysis, corpus

I am new to Python-NLTK. I have written my code using movie reviews data set.
When I put hard coded sample text for sentiment analysis it is working fine but when I try to take user input or fetch the data from text file it shows alphabet level splitting.

for e.g.
When sample text is hard coded like
["Music was awesome", "Special effects are awesome"]
Then splitting is like a
Review : Music was awesome
Review : Special effects are awesome.

But if I asked for user input or fetch the data from text file then it shows review as;
Review: M
Review: u
Review: S
Review: i
Review: c
Review: .

**#For text file Below is my sample code.**

```
t = open ("Sample1.txt", "r")           
File_input = (t.read())
for review in File_input:
  print ("\nReview:", review)
  probdist = classifier.prob_classify(extract_features(review.split()))
  pred_sentiment = probdist.max()

print ("Predicted sentiment:", pred_sentiment) 
print ("Probability:", round(probdist.prob(pred_sentiment), 5))
```

**#For user input Below is my sample code.**

```
User_input = input("Enter your value: ")
for review in User_input:
  print ("\nReview:", review)
  probdist = classifier.prob_classify(extract_features(review.split()))
  pred_sentiment = probdist.max()
print ("Predicted sentiment:", pred_sentiment) 
print ("Probability:", round(probdist.prob(pred_sentiment), 3))
```

plz guide.
Thanks!

Comment: When you do a `for` loop on a file input, each iteration processes one line.  Ask yourself, "what happens when I do a for loop on user input (a string)?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `User_input` variable is a string, so iterating over it is iterating over the chars, what you want to do is remove the `for` loop and treat `User_input` as a review assuming it holds 1 review, otherwise you could define a separating char between reviews and iterate like so:

```
for review in User_input.split(sep_char):
```

Comment: Thanks, It looks fine to me with User_input.split() but (sep_char) means ?

Comment: If you want the user to insert several reviews, you ask a user to separate them using a char (saved in the variable `sep_char`)

Comment: OK! Thanks rotem.